# Receive notification when someone pushed to Master

Tags: bash, windows-10, git-bash

I'm trying to write a script in GitBash that will allow me to be notified when there are changes to remote Master branch that can be fetched and merged. Writing a bash script to automatically pull and detect changes has been pretty easy - however, the issue is I want to be notified when my local was not up to date.

This is a script for work so I don't have admin privileges necessary to send myself an email or desktop notification. I was, understandably, denied admin privileges when I asked. Is there another way to bring this fact to my attention? The command line is minimized most of the time. Is there a way to make the window open itself? I'm out of ideas. I'm on Windows 10 machine by the way.

Note, I also looked into hooks. I can't figure out how to get it to email with the push, so I just did it in Bash.

Comment: Why don't you make it part of your workflow to periodically (daily, etc) to pull master and rebase your feature branch?

Comment: Maybe you could make a short VBScript file that uses `MsgBox()` to pop up a dialog, then run it with `wscript path/to/file`. (You might have to tweak `wscript` -- I don't know how your system path works within GitBash.)